# Sharepoint alert and workflows. Workflow that emails based on list column criteria

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow, sharepoint-alerts

I'm using Sharepoint 2010. I've created a list to track demerits. Each list item has a column for demerit, employee name, supervisor and expiration status.  Expiration status can be valid or expired as the demerit only lasts 6 months.  The objective is for supervisors and the employee to get an email summarizing the Employee’s valid points whenever a new item is created or modified for them.

I set up an alert for all changes but it only sends a summary of the particular list item to the person who setup the alert.

I’ve tried searching all over the place and can’t get a specific result so I finally decided to get Stackoverflow a try.
Hope someone can help.

Comment: Just so you know there is a sharepoint site on here.

Comment: Thanks, I'm quite new here. Didn't know.  I posted there too. Should I take this down?